# How to show a property from an interceptor to JSP?

Tags: java, jsp, struts2

I want to show some data from the current user on my header (a JSP fragment).

I'm using for now the spring security property to get the username, but that user object has a "person" object with personal information like the person's name. So I want to show that name on the header instead the username.

I've create an interceptor to get the name , but, how I can pass this string to the jsp fragment?

This is my src:

**Struts.xml**

```
<interceptor name="user" class="com.myapp.spring.UsuarioInterceptor" />             
            <interceptor-stack name="default">
                <interceptor-ref name="params" />
                <interceptor-ref name="user"/>
                <interceptor-ref name="defaultStack" />
            </interceptor-stack>
 </interceptors>
 <default-interceptor-ref name="default" >

 </default-interceptor-ref>
```

**Interceptor.java**

```
 @Override
 public String intercept(ActionInvocation invocation) throws Exception {
     User usr=getUser();
     if (usr.getPerson()==null){
         name=usr.getUserName();
         return invocation.invoke();
     }
     Person p = usr.getPerson();
     name= p.getName();  
     return invocation.invoke();
 }
```

Comment: You *could* put it in the request, although IMO in general it'd be better to set it on the action, likely marked with an interface with a setter.

Comment: If you are using spring-security then you are doing it wrong. You are better of implementing custom `UserDetails`.

Comment: Can you help me with an example? or a Link? I see this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7737602/example-of-custom-implementation-of-userdetails but didn't work :/

Comment: @rafuru: For this question Dave comment is an answer. For implementing custom `UserDetails` ask another question.