# Routing based on two different relations as roles in spring security

Tags: spring, spring-boot, authentication, spring-mvc, spring-security

I have 2 different relations in mysql admin and user. There is no attribute as role in the relations. Admin needs to login in the /adminLogin and user needs to login in the /userLogin.After successful login they should be redirected to respective dashboards.
Previously I was able to implement having both admin and user in the same relation with attribute for role.

Now need help in handling 2 different relations. Using spring version of 2.7.3

[Tried this stackoverflow solution. But it doesn't seem like handling 2 relations](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41770156/spring-add-custom-user-details-to-spring-security-user)

```
package com.covid.vaccination.bookingslots.model;


import javax.persistence.Column;
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import javax.persistence.GenerationType;
import javax.persistence.Id;

@Entity
public class Admin {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long aId;
    @Column(nullable=false,unique=true,length=30)
    private String email;
    @Column(nullable=false,length=32)
    private String password;
    @Column(length=32)
    private String resetPasswordToken;
    @Column(nullable=false,length=30)
    private String name;
    public Long getaId() {
        return aId;
    }
    public void setaId(Long aId) {
        this.aId = aId;
    }
    public String getEmail() {
        return email;
    }
    public void setEmail(String email) {
        this.email = email;
    }
    public String getPassword() {
        return password;
    }
    public void setPassword(String password) {
        this.password = password;
    }
    public String getResetPasswordToken() {
        return resetPasswordToken;
    }
    public void setResetPasswordToken(String resetPasswordToken) {
        this.resetPasswordToken = resetPasswordToken;
    }
    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }
    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }
    public Admin(Long aId, String email, String password, String resetPasswordToken, String name) {
        super();
        this.aId = aId;
        this.email = email;
        this.password = password;
        this.resetPasswordToken = resetPasswordToken;
        this.name = name;
    }
    public Admin() {
        super();
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
    }
    
}
```

```
package com.covid.vaccination.bookingslots.model;
import java.util.Date;
import java.util.Set;
import javax.persistence.OneToMany;
import javax.persistence.Column;
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import javax.persistence.GenerationType;
import javax.persistence.Id;

@Entity(name="users")
public class User {
    public User() {
        super();
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
    }
    public Long getuId() {
        return uId;
    }
    public void setuId(Long uId) {
        this.uId = uId;
    }
    public String getEmail() {
        return email;
    }
    public void setEmail(String email) {
        this.email = email;
    }
    public String getPassword() {
        return password;
    }
    public void setPassword(String password) {
        this.password = password;
    }
    public String getResetPasswordToken() {
        return resetPasswordToken;
    }
    public void setResetPasswordToken(String resetPasswordToken) {
        this.resetPasswordToken = resetPasswordToken;
    }
    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }
    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }
    public java.util.Date getDOB() {
        return DOB;
    }
    public void setDOB(java.util.Date dOB) {
        DOB = dOB;
    }
    public String getAddressLine1() {
        return addressLine1;
    }
    public void setAddressLine1(String addressLine1) {
        this.addressLine1 = addressLine1;
    }
    public String getAddressLine2() {
        return addressLine2;
    }
    public void setAddressLine2(String addressLine2) {
        this.addressLine2 = addressLine2;
    }
    public Integer getPin() {
        return pin;
    }
    public void setPin(Integer pin) {
        this.pin = pin;
    }
    public Set<Booking> getBookings() {
        return bookings;
    }
    public void setBookings(Set<Booking> bookings) {
        this.bookings = bookings;
    }
    public User(Long uId, String email, String password, String resetPasswordToken, String name, Date dOB,
            String addressLine1, String addressLine2, Integer pin, Set<Booking> bookings) {
        super();
        this.uId = uId;
        this.email = email;
        this.password = password;
        this.resetPasswordToken = resetPasswordToken;
        this.name = name;
        DOB = dOB;
        this.addressLine1 = addressLine1;
        this.addressLine2 = addressLine2;
        this.pin = pin;
        this.bookings = bookings;
    }
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long uId;
    @Column(nullable=false,unique=true,length=30)
    private String email;
    @Column(nullable=false,length=32)
    private String password;
    @Column(length=32)
    private String resetPasswordToken;
    @Column(nullable=false,length=30)
    private String name;
    @Column(nullable=false)
    private java.util.Date DOB;
    @Column(nullable=false,length=50)
    private String addressLine1;
    @Column(nullable=false,length=50)
    private String addressLine2;
    @Column(nullable=false)
    private Integer pin;
    @OneToMany(mappedBy="user")
    private Set<Booking> bookings;
    
}
```