# Spring: Get Custom User Object from SecurityContextHolder

Tags: java, spring, spring-security

I try to implement log-file which stores all logins.

So far I put some code to my LoginHandler but I always get the ERROR:

> org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.User cannot be cast to at.qe.sepm.asn_app.models.UserData

The method in my LoginHandler:

```
@Override
public void onAuthenticationSuccess(HttpServletRequest httpServletRequest, HttpServletResponse httpServletResponse, Authentication authentication) throws IOException, ServletException {
    UserData user = (UserData)SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication().getPrincipal();

    AuditLog log = new AuditLog(user.getUsername() + " [" + user.getUserRole() + "]" ,"LOGGED IN", new Date());
    auditLogRepository.save(log);

    handle(httpServletRequest, httpServletResponse, authentication);
    clearAuthenticationAttributes(httpServletRequest);
}
```

Is it possible to change the return value type from `SecurityContextHolder` to my `UserData` object?

Additional Code:

```
public class MyUserDetails implements UserDetails {

private UserData user;

public UserData getUser(){
    return user;
}

@Override
public String getUsername(){
    return user.getUsername();
}

@Override
public boolean isAccountNonExpired() {
    return false;
}

@Override
public boolean isAccountNonLocked() {
    return false;
}

@Override
public boolean isCredentialsNonExpired() {
    return false;
}

@Override
public boolean isEnabled() {
    return false;
}

@Override
public Collection<? extends GrantedAuthority> getAuthorities() {
    return null;
}

@Override
public String getPassword(){
    return user.getPassword();
}
```

}

```
MyUserDetails myUserDetails = (UserDetails) SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication().getPrincipal();
UserData user = myUserDetails.getUser();
```

The compiler says that `UserDetails` and `MyUserDetails` are incompatible types.

My WebSecurityConfig:

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity()
public class WebSecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

@Autowired
DataSource dataSource;

@Override
protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {

    http.csrf().disable();

    http.headers().frameOptions().disable(); // needed for H2 console

    http.logout()
            .logoutRequestMatcher(new AntPathRequestMatcher("/logout"))
            .invalidateHttpSession(false)
            .logoutSuccessUrl("/login.xhtml");

    http.authorizeRequests()
            //Permit access to the H2 console
            .antMatchers("/h2-console/**").permitAll()
            //Permit access for all to error pages
            .antMatchers("/error/**")
            .permitAll()
            // Only access with admin role
            .antMatchers("/admin/**")
            .hasAnyAuthority("ADMIN")
            //Permit access only for some roles
            .antMatchers("/secured/**")
            .hasAnyAuthority("ADMIN", "EMPLOYEE", "PARENT")
            //If user doesn't have permission, forward him to login page
            .and()
            .formLogin()
            .loginPage("/login.xhtml")
            .loginProcessingUrl("/login")
            .defaultSuccessUrl("/secured/welcome.xhtml").successHandler(successHandler());
    // :TODO: user failureUrl(/login.xhtml?error) and make sure that a corresponding message is displayed

    http.exceptionHandling().accessDeniedPage("/error/denied.xhtml");

    http.sessionManagement().invalidSessionUrl("/error/invalid_session.xhtml");

}

@Bean
public AuthenticationSuccessHandler successHandler() {
    return new LoginHandler();
}

@Autowired
public void configureGlobal(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
    //Configure roles and passwords via datasource
    auth.jdbcAuthentication().dataSource(dataSource)
            .usersByUsernameQuery("select username, password, true from user_data where username=?")
            .authoritiesByUsernameQuery("select username, user_role from user_data where username=?")
            .passwordEncoder(passwordEncoder());
}

@Bean
public PasswordEncoder passwordEncoder(){
    PasswordEncoder encoder = new BCryptPasswordEncoder();
    return encoder;
}
}
```

I also tried to implement the Springs `User`, `UserDetails` and `UserDetailsService` but I failed so far. I have no idea how to adjust these to my project because I use inheritance. My models are `UserData` which inherits to `Parent` and `Employee`. So I also have `UserBaseRepository` and `UserDataRepository`. These all confuses me a lot.

For now I stuck in implementing the methods from the Spring provided User-classes.

Comment: To make a custom `UserDetails` implementation useful you must also do an implementation of `UserDetailsService`.

Comment: what should the service look like? .. implement an UserDetailsRepository and so on? I use inheritance too .. so i have a UserBaseRepository and a UserRepository .. so what repository should my UserDetailsService implement?

Answer (score 1):

The `org.springframework.security.core.UserDetails` should always be implemented by your own `UserData` or another class that wraps your `UserData` instance

For example:

```
public class UserData{
  private username;
  private password;
  /// other user parameters 
 .
 .
 etc
}

public class MyUserDetails implements UserDetails {

  private UserData user;

  public UserData getUser(){
    return user;
  }

  @Override
  public String getUsername(){
    return user.getUsername();
  }

  @Override
  public String getPassword(){
    return user.getPassword();
  }

}
```

And then you cast it like this

```
MyUserDetails myUserDetails = (MyUserDetails)SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication().getPrincipal();

UserData user = myUserDetails.getUser();
```

Comment: i still get an incompatible error.. i added code above .. does it make any differences when i use annotations like `@Entity` in my `UserData`

Comment: No, `@Entity` is not related here

Comment: @SteveOhio I think I fixed incompatible types error.

Comment: @SteveOhio What is exactly the errors​ that you are getting?

Comment: just get the error message from above . i tried to implement userdetails and so on but i failed

Comment: @fujy added some infos in my question above

Comment: @SteveOhio I don't think you are still getting a casting compilation error after holmis83 modification to my answer

Comment: @SteveOhio Implementing `UserDetails` and `UserDetailsService` is quite tricky, check the two examples http://www.baeldung.com/spring-security-authentication-with-a-database and http://www.baeldung.com/spring-security-authentication-with-a-database

Comment: @SteveOhio, also the answer here shows a good example of implementing custom `UserDetails` methods https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7737602/example-of-custom-implementation-of-userdetails